# How to implement gzip compression in such a way that the files compressed path is stored as relative path rather than absolute path?

Tags: redhat, proxy, httpd.conf, gzip

I am trying to implement gzip compression in my Application server machine but when it is served through the proxy(different machine) to the front end the css files are getting broken due to the mixed content error.

CAUSE: mixed-content (Serving contents over http instead through https). This is because the gzip stores the compressed file path as hostname/path/to/file. Here my hostname is Application server machine which does not serve requests as https.

So, is it possible to implement gzip in a such a way that the files are send to the front end using relative path after compressing?

Comment: This is unclear. Gzip can be used for a file format and a compression algorithm. I guess your web server is returning compressed pages? Also when you say path you mean the full URL? (including `http://` , `https://`)

Comment: @Javier .  I am using gzip with apache httpd for response compression. Normally without compression my contents are served to the front-end proxy using relative path resolving the mixed-content error. Now, after gzip compression its passed on with  full path like **http**://hostname/path-to-content. Here, hostname is my app server hostname.

Comment: Sorry I dont have experience on proxies, and probably wont be able to help. But I think you will need to edit your question in order to get a proper answer. That is: Make the title sorter (I will make people not even enter the question). + Try to make the content easier to read: some titles and formatting for the error code might help. + If you managed to make the system work with a simpler setup, describe it, give a list of changes you did to try make compression work. + If something fails, format the error as code and **where** it happened.

Comment: Sorry if editing (and having a look at the [guide about how to ask](http://serverfault.com/help/asking) might take some time. Funny thing is that people usually find the solution to problems when carefully describing them (even to a rubber duck). + Also less funny might be that after taking the effort to edit your question, not every question gets a proper answer. Good luck with that.